# VBA for exel- Automatic make a new sheet with data from x multple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I m a newbie in VBA  and I would appreciate any help.

I have the following   button in an excel workbook using VBA code

```
Sub New_sheet()
Dim x As Integer

    x = InputBox("insert number of new sheets...")
For numtimes = 1 To x
    'Loop by using x as the index number to make x number copies.
    'Replace "Sheet1" with the name of the sheet to be copied.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet (1)").Copy _
       After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet (1)")
Next
End Sub
```

which crates multiple(x) new Sheets depending on the project. I would like to extend this script and crate an extra sheet containig a table with the results of each sheet. The  results are given in the row A8,B8,C8,D8,E8 on every sheet. The table should have x+1 columns (x is the number of the new sheets)

Comment: Can you provide an sample image of how the final result table will look?

Comment: It will be a table with 5 rows  (cell A8,B8,C8,D8,E8 of every sheet) and number of columns will be equal to the sheets (x+1)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the values in each sheet will be manually entered after the worksheets are created.

In this case, you should create a way to trigger the table creation after all data is entered. I would personally use a button for simplicity.

Idea Suggestion:
1.Loop through each worksheet

**https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/142126/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook**

2.Within each sheet loop, record the range of data. You can store them in a **two-dimensional array** or **matrix**.

3.In the sheet you want to create a table, paste the matrix in desired range and select the range of data (+1 column) to create the table.

'This example extends the selected range column by one

**With ActiveSheet.UsedRange**

**Set rng = Range(.Cells, .Offset(1,0)**

**End With**

4. Create Table object from selected range

key syntax
**ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add**

There are many posts online with syntax and examples that cover each step that I have stated above. Hope it helps you figure out the approach you want to take

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will give it a try